# Single "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY" with multiple VALUES return all duplicate id's

Tags: php, mysql

The application needs to send e-mail back to the users when a service becomes available at their home upon updating the covered_addresses table. I'm hoping for a MySQL function to use in 'ON DUPLICATE KEY' before redisigning the database, but failed to find one so far.

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (a, b, c), (g, f, h), (do, re, mi)... // a zillion rows
ON DUPLICATE KEY [function to return all duplicate id's]
```

ps.: I know how to return one duplicate id at a time when performing multiple inserts in a loop, but I'm afraid 60k inserts in a loop would be costly, so I'd need a single query. Any clue?

Comment: You know, duplicate keys only occurs after the insert is performed, so you don't have duplicates before than (and after that, because the insert breaks)? You want to return the duplicates from "a,b,c,g,f,h,do,re,mi"?

Comment: Not sure I'm following you. I have a UNIQUE constraint, so it won't actually duplicate. It will do something when it tries to do it. I need this "something" to be "return these id's when finished inserting all values".

Something like this (4th example):
http://mikefenwick.com/blog/insert-into-database-or-return-id-of-duplicate-row-in-mysql/
... but returning all ID's, not just the last one.

Comment: maybe you could try this. Before the insertion, you check the record using `select col1 from table where col1 in (a, g, do)`. After that you can remove the insertion values based on the return values from that query

Comment: @dArc Thanks. That's my last option. Still looking for a native query though, because any impact on performance will be a pain. It's a shared two digits host and I'll be updating that address table from an excel file... File upload time + PHExcel processing time + bad query = trouble.